# Cloning Attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment

I'm in need of a button that will clone attachments. I have a list of attachments coming from a child object of the case, I am trying to create a button where if the user clicks, it will clone the child object attachment to the parent case object. I'm currently running into the error: **Value 'common.udd.object.EncryptableFfxBlobField$DeferredEncryptableFfxBlobValueImpl@42078f65' cannot be converted from Text to core.filemanager.BlobValue, Error is in expression '{!attachmentBody}' in page VisualforcePage**

Am I using apex:param correctly in this scenario?

Summarized Apex

```
public with sharing class cloneAttachment {

public String attachmentId {get;set;}
public String attachmentName {get;set;}
public Blob attachmentBody {get;set;}
public list<attachment> attachmentsToClone;
public list<attachment> attachmentList;

public cloneAttachment(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.cs = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    std=controller;
}

public list<attachment> getAttachmentList(){
    AttachmentList = [SELECT Id,
                      Body,
                      Name,
                      Description,
                      lastModifiedDate,
                      CreatedById,
                      CreatedDate,
                      OwnerId,
                      CreatedBy.Name,
                      ParentId
                      FROM Attachment
                      WHERE WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT Id
                                               FROM ChildObject
                                               WHERE Case__c = :cs.id) 
                      ORDER BY CreatedDate Desc
                     ];

    if(attachmentList.size()>0)
    return attachmentList;
    return null;
}

public PageReference cloneAttachment() {
    if(attachmentId != null && attachmentName !=null && attachmentBody != null){
        system.debug('This is debug, attachmentId is ' + attachmentId);
        system.debug('This is debug, attachmentName is ' + attachmentName);
        system.debug('This is debug, attachmentBody is ' + attachmentBody);

        Attachment att = new Attachment(name = attachmentName, body = attachmentBody, parentid = attachmentId);
        attachmentsToClone.add(att);

        if(attachmentsToClone.size() > 0){
            insert attachmentsToClone;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Summarized Visualforce

```
<apex:repeat value="{!attachmentList}" var="item">
    <apex:commandLink value="Copy Attachment" action="{!cloneAttachment}">        
        <apex:param name="attachmentId" value="{!item.id}" assignTo="{!attachmentId}"/>
        <apex:param name="attachmentName" value="{!item.name}" assignTo="{!attachmentName}"/>
    <apex:param name="attachmentBody" value="{!item.body}" assignTo="{!attachmentBody}"/>
    </apex:commandLink> 

</apex:repeat
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are cloning the attachment then only just pass the attachment id and parentId to the controller.

In the controller `cloneAttachment()` method, retrieve the child attachment information from SOQL.

Then do the cloning by using `clone()` method and finally update the parentId of the attachment and insert the record.

```
Attachment fileAttachment = [SELECT SELECT Id,
                              Body,
                              Name,
                              Description,
                              ParentId
                              FROM Attachment
                              WHERE Id=:attachmentId] 


    Attachment newFile = fileAttachment.clone();
    newFile.ParentId = paramParentId;
    insert newFile;
```

If you want to pass multiple attachments then handle that into a list and perform DML on the list.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to your immediate question, I wanted to note that it's surprisingly easy to do this via visual workflow.

I'm using a custom button to copy attachments from email to case.  I have set it up so I can select which attachments to move over w a clever hack I picked up from developer force.

See these two posts if this is an approach you want to try.

http://goravseth.com/working-with-attachments-in-visual-workflow

http://goravseth.com/using-a-dynamic-choice-to-select-multiple-records-in-visual-workflow